# Electron fields does not anticommute at space-like points

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, causality, anticommutator

In the end of page 804 and beginning of page 805 of Streater's paper

Outline of axiomatic relativistic quantum field theory

which can be find here https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0034-4885/38/7/001

the author said "Perturbation theory suggests that in a Hilbert space approach (positive-definite metric) $\psi$ does not anticommute at space-like separation." What did the author mean here? Any reference for this?